# DataGridView backcolor of the first row is white although the selection backcolor is transparent

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to hide the selection option of my `DataGridView` so that it seems always like nothing has been selected.

I have set the `SelectionBackColor` property of my `DataGridView` to `Transparent`. But when it loads, the first row's back color is always white although it turns `transparent` as I select other rows. But at the beginning it is always white.

This is how it looks after loading:

[image]

And this is how it looks as I click on another row:

[image]

How can I make it so that it always looks like the second picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deselect the first row after you've filled the grid. By default the first row is selected when you fill it, but it is possible to have no rows at all selected.

```
DataTable dtb = new DataTable("D");
dtb.Columns.Add("C1");
dtb.Rows.Add("A");
dtb.Rows.Add("B");
dtb.Rows.Add("C");
dtb.Rows.Add("D");
dtb.Rows.Add("E");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtb;
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = false;
}
```